# Programming on a chromebook with EV3

Tags: ev3, programming

How do I install the new Lego block programming software on a chromebook? We have the standard version, but want the new one that looks like Scratch.

Answer (score 5):

Can you just install Scratch? [MIT supports EV3 directly](https://scratch.mit.edu/ev3)

Comment: Agree with @rschulz, Scratch has a Chromebook EV3 version.

Answer (score 5):

The new Scratch-based software from LEGO Education is called *EV3 Classroom*.

The link on the [LEGO Education EV3 downloads page](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3/software#downloads) for Chromebooks takes you to the [EV3 Classroom app at the Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.education.ev3classroom). So it seems that you will need a [Chromebook capable of running Android apps](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps) in order to use it.

As of this writing, the equivalent retail version of the software doesn't seem to be available yet on platforms other than macOS.